# ¿Cómo establecer un tiempo de vida a un socket en Java?

Tags: java, socket

Estoy creando una conexión socket en java pero necesito establecer un tiempo de vida para este socket. Actualmente estoy trabajando con Java 8 y esto es lo que he intentado:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
socket.setSoLinger(true, 10000);
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
```

Por alguna razón esto no se cumple y el tiempo de vida del socket no está funcionando. ¿Tienen alguna otra idea?

Comment: Ese parámetro es una configuración de timeout cuando se establece conexión con un cliente. No tiene nada que ver con el tiempo que dura el socket "abierto". Yo levantaría el socket en un hilo y validaría externamente cuánto tiempo pasa hasta que sea hora y terminaría la ejecución del hilo.